# Golang converting between time formats

Tags: string, go, time

I am trying to parse a time string which is transported on the wire as JSON. In the below code, I am just experimenting the time parsing as part of that:

```
currentTime := time.Now().String()
//currentTime has the time
t1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, currentTime)
fmt.Println(t1.String())
```

The last but one line mangles the time and produces the output:
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

See this GoPlayground:https://play.golang.org/p/Q_G_qYcnaHP

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? `Parse` is to return a `Time` variable when you have a string in an expected format. I think you want to do the opposite, which can be done using `Format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're omitting the error returned by [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse). Never omit errors.

If you print the error:

```
currentTime := time.Now().String()
t1, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, currentTime)
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(t1.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L6dGK1rXyQ1)):

```
parsing time "2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001" as "T"
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

The problem is that [`Time.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String) produces the text representation in a different format than specified by `time.RFC3339`. `Time.String()` produces output using the format:

```
"2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
```

While you attempt to parse it from the format:

```
RFC3339 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

Obviously that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@icza is right. You should check it on godoc https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String

```
String returns the time formatted using the format string

"2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
```

In case if you are new to golang, you may want to know the right way.

Here is how:

```
formatstr:="2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
currentTime := time.Now().String()
t1, _ := time.Parse(formatstr, currentTime)
fmt.Println(t1.String())
```